# Base SDK 4.0 missing but i just installed the 4.1, how can i test for 4.0?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

I used ot have the 3.x then i forgot to update to 4.0 then yesterday i installed the 4.1 sdk, so now i have the 4.0 missing...

how ca i test if the app works on iphone 4.0, o better , how can i be sure it works on iphone with older sdk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure two settings in your project, the first is the BASE SDK,

[image]

this should be set at the version that you have installed so 4.1 and the second setting (Deployment target) is the lowest version that you want to target

[image]

If you want to target 4.0 and greater just change the target to 4.0

Answer (score 1):

The base target thing was answered - as for testing 3.x, you either have to keep an older XCode around to test with, or an older device.  My recommendation is an older Touch or iPhone.

After 4.2 comes out for the iPad I'm not sure I would bother supporting the 3.x platform much longer.